# How to sort a data by assigned name for a column

Tags: r

I want to use the order() function in R to sort a data by the column.

For example, with the data.frame below

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <-as.data.frame(cbind(NUM=seq(1:5),RES=runif(5,0,10)))

> with(data = mydata, mydata[order(RES),])
  NUM      RES
5   5 2.016819
1   1 2.655087
2   2 3.721239
3   3 5.728534
4   4 9.082078
```

It's OK. But when I do the same thing with assigned name for a column I got an unexpected result.

```
colname <- "RES"

> with(data = mydata, mydata[order(colname),])
  NUM      RES
1   1 2.655087
```

I'm wondering if anybody has faced the same problem and/or if you have a solution for that. Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: I think `with()` is a little bit overkill here. Instead, I would just qualify the column under the data.frame. For the case of a hard-coded column name this would be `mydata[order(mydata$RES),]`, and for the case of a variable column name this would be `mydata[order(mydata[,colname]),]`, or if you prefer, `mydata[order(mydata[[colname]]),]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get()` to return the value of a named object:

```
with(data = mydata, mydata[order(get(colname)),])

#  NUM      RES
#5   5 2.016819
#1   1 2.655087
#2   2 3.721239
#3   3 5.728534
#4   4 9.082078
```